# в android studio при попытке создать vector asset пишет not ready

Tags: android-studio, flutter

в `android studio` (в `flutter` проекте) при попытке создать `vector asset` пишет `not ready`, что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите добавить это в Android, то откройте проект выбрав папку android. В Flutter это нельзя добавлять, там идут связки с Java/Kotlin.